# Does eq work if the form is being dynamically created?

Tags: jquery

I have a form where people enter elements and it autogrows.  I wanted to do some math on the data being entered but I'm having problems capaturing the contents of the input field.  Here's the original program I'm working with ( http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/WaL84/ ) and I did some reading and believe .eq is the command I need to get the second last element of the auto growing list(I can't get the last element because its always blank on a auto growing list).

My end goal would be to take all the numbers and return the total or average,etc...

I tried `var from = $("#siblings").eq(-1).val();` and -2 but it keeps giving me the value of only the first cell(for example if I enter 1,2,3,4,5 on each cell then I'll keep getting 1).

If it helps here's the code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input[name='siblings']").on('keydown',
        function()
        {

           //is it the last input?
           if(this==$("input[name='siblings']:last",this.form)[0])
           {
            //insert an empty clone of the current input
            $(this).after($(this).clone(true).val(''));

           var from = $("#siblings").eq(-1).val();

           $("div#total").append("value = " + from + "<br>");       
           }
         });        
});
```

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="input.js">
</script>
<style type="text/css">
input{display:block}​
</style>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<p> test </p>
<form>
    <div id="inputform" name="inputform">
        <input id="siblings" name="siblings"> 
    </div>
</form>
<div id="total">
hello
</div>
&nbsp;
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `$("#siblings")` always returns only one element. Do you create **several** elements with the same `id`?

Comment: @zerkms yes, each element has the same name, I think its because I'm cloning the section. Is there another way to get the same outcome?

Comment: I didn't ask about `name` attribute, I asked about `id`. `$("#siblings")` - searches the element with `id = siblings`. And `id` is assumed to be unique

Comment: @zerkms yes the `id` is the same.

Comment: `id` should be unique for each element on the page. That's why it is called "id"

Comment: @zerkms I'm new to jquery but I understand what your saying. How can I create a unique id when I'm cloning an element? I thought it just copies as is.

Comment: it's not jquery thing, it is DOM. If you don't need `id` (do you?) - just don't specify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the condition in the `if()` clause is confusing if not actually wrong.

Second, I think you want to get the value from the input element on which the keydown event fired, in other words simply `this` or `$(this)`, inside the handler. There's no point getting the value from the freshly cloned element because it has been deliberately emptied.

Try this :

```
$("input[name='siblings']").on('keyup', function(e) {
    if(e.which === 9) return;
    var $this = $(this);
    if (this == $this.siblings().andSelf().last().get(0)) {
        //insert an empty clone of the current input
        $this.clone(true).val('').insertAfter(this);
        $("div#total").append("value = " + $this.val() + "<br>");
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried it and it doesn't seem to be working, here's the end result, am I doing something wrong? http://jsfiddle.net/uHLHH/2/

Comment: Whoops, I forget `andSelf()`. Maybe your if clause was not so confusing after all :)  Oh yes, I also changed 'keydown' to 'keyup', otherwise the keystroke has not yet happened.  Answer edited and fiddle updated - http://jsfiddle.net/uHLHH/4/

Comment: no worries(I'm learning so half of the stuff I write doesn't follow any logic anyway lol).  Its still not working, your example doesn't actually output any results after the first item.  If you take your example and type 1,2,3,4,5,6 in each field after the first item it won't pick up anything.

Comment: It works for me but only insofar as I understand what's required. The only constraint appears to be that tabbing into the last field hasthe undesirable effect of appending a new field immediately.

Comment: The appending part I can fix, but when I'm running it I don't get any result, it just appends `value = `(its blank). I'm running the updated fiddle you posted..is it posting values of what you enter when you run it?

Comment: By returning immediately if the keystroke was a tab, then it works according to my understanding of the spec. Yes, values are posted. http://jsfiddle.net/uHLHH/5/.

Comment: thanks it works, but what is the point of `if(e.which === 9) return;` if I leave it then I can't go above double digits but without it returns nothing.

Comment: `e.which` is the keycode of the keystroke that triggered the event. `e.which == 9` tests for tab.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `.last()`:

```
var from = $('input[name="siblings"]').last().val();
```

Also, it would be easier if you used classes along with names to identify elements, as it's much simpler to type `.siblings`.

Comment: thanks Blender but its not working(I get no valued returned). I tested it with .first() and that gave me the first result so I think the synax is correct but I think last doesn't work because after I add a new input field last is a blank field?  Because I was going to average or get the total of all fields, is there a way to somehow do it by index(like -1 or something so later I can iterate over all fields if the user changes a field)?  Also I'll learn about adding classes, thanks for the advice.

Comment: It should. jQuery doesn't cache objects like this.

Comment: Here's the code: http://jsfiddle.net/uHLHH/1/  with last its always blank, but with first it repeats the first item always.

Comment: You are cloning and appending the `input` element (I'd give it a `type="text"` for safety) before you're fetching the last element's value. In effect, you are fetching an empty element's `val()` which should be empty.

Comment: I'm super new to jquery so I'm sorry if I'm wrong but isn't the fact that I'm fetching the last item(which is empty) the reason .last() doesn't work?

Comment: Yep. Either put the `clone()` code after the `.last()` call, or use `.eq(-2)` instead of `.last()`.

Comment: I'm kind of back to my original problem if I do `var from = $('input[name="siblings[]"]').eq(-2).val;` then I don't actually get anything meaningful(the second last item I'm expecting)